# How can I return back videos which was removed?

Tags: video, delete, rename

When I rename "videos" folder, the videos in that have been removed.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked you recycle bin?

Comment: There are not videos in recycle bin.

Comment: There are not videos in recycle bin.

Comment: The graphic shows files in /Home/Pictures. Are you looking in the right folder? You could try opening a terminal and usind the find command - see man page here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Comment: Is the full path to your Videos directory shown in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks? (you can open a Terminal window and run the command `cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` to check)

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you:)

Comment: how was it resolved?

Comment: @AsilbekNormuminov please create an answer so other people with similar problems can learn of your experiences.

Comment: My videos which I lost were in Home folder as "Videolarim" name.